# Overloaded input operator failing automated simple input test

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

So I'm failing a simple input test for one of assignment questions. I'm to parse two integers separated by a white space. The two integers are used in the private members num and denom of the Rationalnumber type I have defined as a class. Is there something obviously unconventional I am using in or missing from this code? This code works for all my tests.

```
std::istream &operator>>( std::istream &is, Rationalnumber &r ) {   
    Rationalnumber::in++;   // increment counter

    // get the num
    string n;
    getline(cin,n,' ');
    stringstream ssnum(n);
    ssnum >> r.num;

    // get the denom
    string d;
    getline(cin,d,'\n');
    stringstream ssdenom(d);
    ssdenom >> r.denom;

    return is;
}
```

Comment: The code could be shortened quite a bit and there is no error checking. Other than that, what was the input it was failing on?

Comment: Everybody else seems to have no issues passing the test, so there has not been much discussion on what the test tests. I will try something else myself to see if it passes.

Comment: It seems you are assuming that the second number comes at the end of the line.  Is that a valid assumption?

Comment: Yep, I'm pretty sure...what else could I do instead? Maybe I'll have it intake a dynamic vector.

Comment: Why read in as strings and the converting to a number (I presume) instead of reading directly into the numbers? Can be done with only one statement: `is >> r.num >> r.denum;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code passes the test!:

```
std::istream &operator>>( std::istream &is, Rationalnumber &r ) {   
    Rationalnumber::in++;   // increment counter

    int in;
    is >> in;
    r.numerator(in);
    is >> in;
    r.denominator(in);

    return is;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code fails in, at least, two obvious ways:

1. If a different whitespace than space is used, e.g., `'\t'`, it isn't recognized by your code.
2. The input operator doesn't indicate failure when it is given invalid inputs, e.g., when the input is `"a b"` rather than numbers.

Conventionally, when input fails, the valuevread remains unchanged. This is also not true for your implementation. To fix things up the code can actually be simplified and made a lot fadter in the process. As this is clearly a homework assignment I don't think it is appropriate to provide the code, though.